# Laravel 5.4 - Error after Uploading Files to Server

Tags: php, laravel, web, host

My project works fine in my localhost but when I upload I get the following error :

```
(3/3) ErrorException The Mix manifest does not exist.
```

Any ideas how I can solve it?  I have previously had some other errors (like welcome.blade not defined).

Comment: Can you show the whole error you're getting?

Comment: (3/3) ErrorException
The Mix manifest does not exist. (View: /home/u6871066/resources/views/vendor/adminlte/layouts/landing.blade.php) (View: /home/u6871066/resources/views/vendor/adminlte/layouts/landing.blade.php)

Comment: so it works in my computer but in host server its not working..

Comment: the custom page which i created works in website now but, the templates of laravel is not working. so it seems like its about visual part of website? at least i think so.

Comment: did you upload your files through git?

Comment: no i didnt do it through git, does it differs?

Comment: edited for clarity

Comment: ok i do these now! i will tell you.

Comment: ok build succesfull after npm install + npm run dev. should i do npm run production also?

Comment: What is the new error? Is it still the same. Mix manifest error should be gone after npm run production

Comment: i didnt doo npm production.. i thought npm install and run dev was enough. let me do it now.

Comment: now I will upload again, and tell you.

Comment: So I uploaded again and checked. It gives same error in website but now in localhost visuals are broken in website, like templates, styles etc..

Comment: So as i see this error is about something else..

Comment: ok guys problem solved, my friend helped me about it. So problem was these structure was looking codes to work in public folder, so it was looking for that folder but we had public_html so thats why it was showing this error..

Answer (score 3):

Just go to under the app/Providers, you will find your AppServiceProvider file and inside boot() method make the binding as below.

```
  $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return base_path().'/../public_html';
});
```

Comment: Just used the above to fix my GoDaddy deployment.

Answer (score 1):

You may also try as run the given command

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

run this in your terminal

npm install

npm run dev

if in production it is

npm run production

Comment: Gave error like ;


npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script 'npm run development'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR!     npm run development
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\xampp\htdocs\torbali\npm-debug.log

Comment: errors starts with  ; 


> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

'cross-env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: updated the answer. this is probably an error because you don't have the node_modules dependencies in order to compile the script

Comment: ok build succesfull after npm install + npm run dev. should i do npm run production also?

Comment: so i did same and uploaded files to server again i get same error again..

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload your /public/mix-manifest.json file to the server. This is a small file that contain versioning information for JavaScript and CSS assets to help with cache busting. In your Blade files you can use `mix('some-file.js')` and so long as it’s in the mix manifest Laravel will create a URL with the a version querystring. See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix